# Python, Universal Robots, Ethernet problem

Tags: python

This is in regards to a UR 10 running 3.5.3.10825.  For the script urx_get_robot.py

```
import urx
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
        robot = urx.Robot("192.168.1.106")

    finally:
        robot.close()
```

When I run the command python3 urx_get_robot.py, here is what I get.

```
WARNING:ursecmon:tried 11 times to find a packet in data, advertised packet size: -2, type: 3
WARNING:ursecmon:Data length: 68
WARNING:ursecmon:tried 11 times to find a packet in data, advertised packet size: -2, type: 3
WARNING:ursecmon:Data length: 1092
WARNING:ursecmon:tried 11 times to find a packet in data, advertised packet size: -2, type: 3
WARNING:ursecmon:Data length: 1418
INFO:ursecmon:Remove 79 bytes of garbage at begining of packet
INFO:urx:Closing sockets to robot
```

It's unknown to me whether this is a problem with the robot version and urx or if the UR 10 is behaving abnormally, because when I run the following script

```
import socket

HOST = "192.168.1.106"    # The remote host
PORT = 30002              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

for i in range(2):
    data = s.recv(32768)
    print ("Received", data)

s.close()
```

This is what prints:

```
Received b'\x00\x00\x007\x14\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\x03\tURControl\x03\x05\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0015-02-2018, 13:17:59\x00\x00\x00\x18\x14\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\x0c\x00\x00w$\x00\x00w$\x01'
Received b"\x00\x00\x05F\x10\x00\x00\x00/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]\xdbX\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfb\x01\xc0\x07\x89e\x88\x88Z0\xc0\x07\x89r\x08\x88Z0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbeR\xf0\x01B@/\x1bA\xd7\xeb\x81A\xde\x9e'\xfd\xc0\x00xWh\x88Z0\xc0\x00xc\xe8\x88Z0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\xa2\x99\x01B@\x00\x00A\xe2\xcc\xc8A\xf6\xbd\xb3\xfd\xbf\xf9\xd2\xecQ\x10\xb4`\xbf\xf9\xd3\x11\xd1\x10\xb4`\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@K\x97\x9fBA\x85\x1fA\xea\x14vA\xfb\x14\xdd\xfd\xc0\x04\xff'\xe8\x88Z0\xc0\x04\xff'\xe8\x88Z0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00=\xd3P\x01B@]/A\xecz\xddB\x13\xf9I\xfd\xbf\xf43\xb6Q\x10\xb4`\xbf\xf43\xdb\xd1\x10\xb4`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xee\xe0\x02B@|\xeeB\x04\n9B\x08\x12B\xfd\xbf\xf9[#\xd1\x10\xb4`\xbf\xf9[=Q\x10\xb4`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00>\x1e|\x01B@|\xeeB\x02O\xcfB\x14\xf3\xe1\xfd\x00\x00\x00e\x04\xbf\xecW9\xf6v8~?\x86E\xben\xda\x1d\xcf?\xd0\xb5\x01\x13\xf0\xdd\x9a\xc0\x01r\xf8\xc5\xdf\xe30?\xbb\xe0\x81\x1c\xd0=.@\x01)\x90m\ni\xdc\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe1\x05l\xe9\xb4/\xac(\xcf\x8b\x8b\x06\xfewZ\xee\x8f\x80\xab\xa6\r\x05\x96\x94]w?+\xdetTHF)\xbf\xcf\x91\xe94i$\x17?\xd2\x95\xf0\xc7\x04\xe8f\xbf\xa6:\x9fBx7\x9b\xbf9\xb66k\xf0\x19\xd2\xbfG\x1c\x80\xb58>K?\x01E,o7#\x19\xbf\xe3\x00$r\x96\xbc\xb0\xbf\xe2A\x05\xca\xf2Ps?\x05\xcf\xe3\x81\x92^\xbc\xbe\xea\x12\x1cX\xca^\xe7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xc0f\xabF\xba\xab,@68\xe3%\x06l\xbf\xc08\xf3\x0f\xa6\x14\x87\xdf@\x07\x1f\xde*\xa2b3?\xbd\x9a\xdb\xa4\\\xaez?\xb7\x98\x92\x06\xcd,\xc1?\xf9!\x81\tW\xbfd\xbf{\x94\xb1\xdb\xc5\x7fp\xbf\x82yTQk\x119?\xf9 \xa3\xb7-\xdd\xe7\xbf\xf9$\xafS\xac\xb9\x9a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x005\t@\nC\x04\xe3\xe50\x19\xbf\xf0ZE\x81R\xb3a\xc0\x0e\xf4'\xe1N\x07b\xbf\xe8\x01/\xef\x00v?\xbf\xd7\xfb\xe9:\x88\xf3\xd1\xc0\x00\x0fi\x90'}[\x00\x00\x00J\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x01?p\x7f\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00?p\x7f\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?pbM\xe0\x00\x00\x00?pbM\xe0\x00\x00\x00A\xfc \x00BA~>?\x80UD>\\\x82\xd3\x01\x00\x00\xc2D[d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x02\x01\x01?\xa7\x1b\xfd@\x00\x00\x00?\xa6\xa1\x96\xe0\x00\x00\x00C\xe5[2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B@\x00\x00\xfd\x00\x00\x01\xbd\x06\xc0\x19W\x99(,/c@\x19W\x99(,/c\xc0\x19W\x99(,/c@\x19W\x99(,/c\xc0\x19W\x99(,/c@\x19W\x99(,/c\xc0\x19W\x99(,/c@\x19W\x99(,/c\xc0\x19W\x99(,/c@\x19W\x99(,/c\xc0\x19W\x99(,/c@\x19W\x99(,/c@\x02Z\xeb\xd1\xc7\x0c\xff@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x02Z\xeb\xd1\xc7\x0c\xff@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\n\xbb\x94\xed\xdd\xc6\xb1@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\n\xbb\x94\xed\xdd\xc6\xb1@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\n\xbb\x94\xed\xdd\xc6\xb1@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\n\xbb\x94\xed\xdd\xc6\xb1@D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xf0\xc1R8-se?\xf6W\x18J\xe7D\x87?\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xf3333333?\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbf\xe3\x95\x81\x06$\xdd/\xbf\xe2PH\x16\xf0\x06\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xc0K]\xccc\xf1A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xc4\xfc\x04\xc8\xbc\x9c\xd4?\xbd\x9e\x83\xe4%\xae\xe6?\xb7\x9akP\xb0\xf2|?\xf9!\xfbTREP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xf9!\xfbTREP\xbf\xf9!\xfbTREP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00=\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\xb1B\x92\x7fK\xe2\xea\x00\x00\x00\x08\x08\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00+\n\xc2D[d\x00\x00\xbf\xd1\xff\xb4W\xae\x12[\xbf\xad\x1d5^\xed\xcae?\xe5_7\x1ff\x17\xd1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

No matter how many times the loop repeats there are always similar characters printed.  Should the robot be continually sending data like that?  Any help you can give would be so so appreciated.

**Edit 1:** From what I've read, it seems the robot is behaving normally by continually writing data to port 30002.  The problem is that, after the warnings from ursecmon above, my urx script hangs at, for example, `print("Current tool pose is: " + rob.getl())`

**Edit 2:** The problem persists after updating the robot to 3.9.

Comment: have you examined the printed data?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  The printed data are meaningless to me.  Most of it is hex characters.  My only idea was trying data.decode('utf-8') but that yielded an error about illegal characters.  The thing that seems odd to me is why is the robot continually sending to the port?

Comment: Edit: it's apparently normal for the robot to send continuously over this port (for MATLAB to use?)  http://www.zacobria.com/universal-robots-knowledge-base-tech-support-forum-hints-tips/knowledge-base/testing-tcp-connection-host-to-ur/